# SSL Library Error: -8181 Certificate has expired

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, centos5

After a `yum update`, there is an error when starting apache, in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
[notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[error] SSL Library Error: -8181 Certificate has expired
[error] Unable to verify certificate 'Server-Cert'. Add "NSSEnforceValidCerts off" to nss.conf so the server can start until the problem can be resolved.
```

Now I temporary put `NSSEnforceValidCerts off` in `nss.conf` to have the site running. How can I fix the error?

Comment: Do you really use `mod_nss` ? Can you try to remove `nss.conf` from `/etc/httpd/conf.d` then restart Apache and test your website. What happens ?

Comment: Apache starts OK if `nss.conf` is removed from `/etc/httpd/conf.d`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that a certificate was created when `mod_nss` was installed.

This certificate has expired, preventing the restarting of `httpd` (Apache).

Do you really use `mod_nss` ?

If you aren't using `mod_nss` then your best bet is to simply uninstall the package.

However you have some alternatives :

- Remove `nss.conf` from `/etc/httpd/conf.d` (this will cause `mod_nss` to not be loaded).
- Uninstall/re-install your nss rpm modules. On re-installation a new 
  certificate will be generated and your problem will go away for a
  few more years :

  ```
  rpm -e mod_nss
  rm /etc/httpd/alias/*
  yum install mod_nss
  service httpd restart
  ```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is reading this, you don't need to remove the mod_nss. You can just re-issue the certificate:

- Take a backup of the current alias folder
  **mv /etc/httpd/alias /etc/httpd/alias_2023_10_23**
- Create a new alias folder
  **mkdir /etc/httpd/alias**
- Generate the new certificate, when asked for a password press enter (no password)
  **gencert /etc/httpd/alias/**
- Verify the new certificate is valid
  **certutil -d /etc/httpd/alias -L -n Server-Cert**
- Change group ownership for the following files:

```
chown root:apache /etc/httpd/alias/secmod.db 
chown root:apache /etc/httpd/alias/key3.db
chown root:apache /etc/httpd/alias/cert8.db
ln -s /usr/lib64/libnssckbi.so libnssckbi.so
```

- Change permissions on the files

```
chmod 640 /etc/httpd/alias/secmod.db
chmod 640 /etc/httpd/alias/key3.db
chmod 640 /etc/httpd/alias/cert8.db
```

- Restart Apache
  **systemctl start httpd**

Answer (score 2):

The `Server-Cert` is expired, checked by:

```
certutil -d /etc/httpd/alias -L -n Server-Cert
```

At the moment, `mod_nss` is disable by removing `nss.conf` from `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dnf remove mod_nss
rm /etc/httpd/alias/*
dnf install mod_nss
systemctl restart httpd
```

the important is remove /etc/httpd/alias/* before reinstall it